# What is the best way to set a new filteredImages array with useState?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

What is the best way to set a new `filteredImages` array with `useState`?

I notice I’m doing `return attachments.filter(attachment => { …` twice, so wondered if I can do it once.

```
  const [filteredImages, setFilteredImages] = useState(() => {
    return attachments.filter(attachment => {
      const {name, isImage} = attachment;
      if (name) {
        const newFileFormat = name.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
        return isImage && newFileFormat !== 'tiff';
      }
    });
  });

…

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredImages(() => {
      return attachments.filter(attachment => {
        const {name, isImage} = attachment;
        if (name) {
          const newFileFormat = name.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
          return isImage && newFileFormat !== 'tiff';
        }
      });
    });
  }, [attachments, card.attachments]);
```

I passes an argument to `setFilteredImages` to set a new `filteredImages` array but it didn’t work.

Comment: `useEffect` must run when the state is created right?

Comment: @Mutex Yes I think so.

Comment: What's wrong with extracting the logic to a function and reusing it?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Currently this is not looping infinitely.

Comment: Right, I misread earlier and have edited my comment

Comment: Set `useState` to be an empty array initially. Then in your render, check if the `filteredImages` has `length > 0`. The `useEffect` is fine as is.